# Render component HTML in the parent DWT

Tags: 2009, dwt

In the schema of a component A, there is a "link to component B" field. I want to retrieve the template of that component B in my component A template.
I tried the following syntax but it does not work:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Component.Fields.slideshare" -->@@RenderComponentPresentation()@@<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

slideshare is the field name in my component A
Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't now what you are trying to do... components don't have DWT's. I guess you mean you want to access a component link field withing a DWT in a Component Template?

Comment: Yes , i expressed myself poorly. I try again: 
In the schema of a component A, there is a "link to component B" field. I want to retrieve the template of that component B in my component A template

Comment: You can't retrieve template of component B because when linking components there is no template involved. Do you mean you want to render (Component B with Template B) in Template A?

Comment: Yes that's what i want ! 
I tried this :  @RenderComponentPresentation(Field, "tcm:125-48340-32")@@ but not working unfortunately. the tcm is component B's template

Comment: @@RenderComponentPresentation(Component.Fields.slideshare, "tcm:125-48340-32")@@ should work. Please note that the field names are case sensitive :)

Comment: Well actually i think the problem is my field is itself in an embedded schema and not directly in the component's schema.
So i need to find a way to navigate to that schema. Something like this:

Component.MYEMBEDDED_SCHEMA.Fields.slideshare.
Is this possible ?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only makes sense to call `@@RenderComponentPresentation()@@` without arguments when you are iterating over a package item of type ComponentArray. This is what you are doing when you use code such as:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Components" -->
@@RenderComponentPresentation()@@
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

after using the default TBB "Extract Components From Page" further up the pipeline. In this case, the components will have been added to the array, and decorated with properties, including the ID of the component template. You can examine these properties by using the technique described [here](https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/wiki/LogPropertiesOfItemsInPackage).

You can call `RenderComponentPresentation()` and pass in the component ID and component template ID as parameters. Depending on what you are trying to do, it might be enough to do this in your DWT TBB.

If you really need to iterate over the components in a Template..Repeat, then you might do better to create a ComponentArray yourself and push it to the package. You can see an example of doing this [here](https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/blob/master/TridionPracticeCookbook/PartitionComponentPresentations.cs#L87). (Note that in the example, the components are already decorated with the component template property, so in your case you'd have to do that.)  Obviously the logic for determining which component template to use would depend on your particular use-case.