# Use of a tcmUri list in component template

Tags: templating, 2009, dwt

I have another problem with a list of TcmUris I pushed to the package and try to use.

I'm trying to render the different components whom ids are in the list "slideshareList" with their common template which is the 2 second parameter provided in the RenderComponentPresentation method.

The code below is what I tried so far (not working, displaying nothing)

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Paragraph" -->
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="TemplateRepeatIndex = paragraphindex" -->

// SOME CODE     

// WHAT IS NEW
<div>@@RenderComponentPresentation(slideshareList[${paragraphindex}],"tcm:125-48340-32")@@</div>

<!-- TemplateEndIf -->
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish, did you want to render the content of the linked Components? Please edit your question and provide a bit more information/detail.

Comment: I've added some informations, i hope it's more clear!
Thank you

Comment: What is `paragraphindex` and where is that coming from?  I suspect, at first glance, that this is saying "if 0 == ''", which is why nothing is happening.  Also I think you need a double equals in the DWT condition.

Comment: is this a duplicate of http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15164/render-component-template-from-link-to-component-field-tridion-2009? and possibly  http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15119/render-component-html-in-the-parent-dwt In that case its better to ask a single question and ensure you get a valid answer than to continue creating new questions around the same.

Comment: Actually , i made a mistake i used TemplateRepeatIndex and not ParagraphIndex as parameter. 
To be completely honest with you , i have no idea what paragraphindex is yet. This is not my code and i just try to understand it right now.
The thing i can say is the code definitely goes into the TemplateBeginIf because there are a lot of instructions inside that are reached. I just deleted them for more clarity

Comment: Yes i did write those questions a few days ago. But didn't get any answers helping me. The approach was also different, i was doing everything inside the template while now i get the components ids in a TBB that sends them to the package in a list. So the problem is not really the same.

Not a lot of people know Tridion it seems ( and i understand a little why actually ). If i had let those questions, nobody would have paid attention to it after a few days.

Comment: the reason why you might not be getting instant answers is **a.** because your questions are not detailed enough, and **b.** because you are asking questions about a templating model which nobody uses much anymore. If you were to upgrade to SDL Web 8, you could start using DXA and then you don't need so much Tridion Templating knowledge. But in any case, it is not wise to create new questions and leave old ones behind, if you don't want to edit your question, consider deleting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are roughly trying to do I think should read something like

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Paragraph" -->
  <div>
    @@RenderComponentPresentation(slideshareList[${TemplateRepeatIndex}],"tcm:125-48340-32")@@
  </div>
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

Don't try to assign variables through the Template Expression Language, you can't do that. But in this example `slideshareList` is also still undefined. My Template Expression Language is a bit rusty, haven't used it for years, but try searching this site on similar questions, since there are a whole bunch of answer out there.

Other options you have in regards to using embedded Component links is checking out this Tridion Practice Cookbooks https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/wiki/IteratingOverMultivalueEmbeddedFields and the DWT Get Extension https://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/dreamweaver_get_extension.aspx

Comment: It works! thank you.